# Pass column names to dplyr::coalesce() when writing a custom function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyselect

I'm trying to write a function that will wrap `dplyr::coalesce()`, and will take in a data object and column names to coalesce. So far, my attempts have failed.

### Example data

```r
library(dplyr)

df <-
  data.frame(col_a = c("bob", NA, "bob", NA, "bob"), 
                 col_b = c(NA, "danny", NA, NA, NA), 
                 col_c = c("paul", NA, NA, "paul", NA))

##   col_a col_b col_c
## 1   bob  <NA>  paul
## 2  <NA> danny  <NA>
## 3   bob  <NA>  <NA>
## 4  <NA>  <NA>  paul
## 5   bob  <NA>  <NA>
```

#### Taking a stub at writing a custom function

```r
coalesce_plus_1 <- function(data, vars) {

  data %>%
    mutate(coalesced_col = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(tidyselect::vars_select(names(.), vars))))

}
```

```r
coalesce_plus_2 <- function(data, vars) {
  
  data %>%
    mutate(coalesced_col = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(vars)))
  
}
```

```r
coalesce_plus_3 <- function(data, vars) {
  
  data %>%
    mutate(coalesced_col = coalesce({{ vars }}))
  
}
```

#### The results...

***`coalesce_plus_1()`***

```r
df %>%
  coalesce_plus_1(data = ., vars = c(col_a, col_b, col_c))
```

> Error: object 'col_a' not found.

However:

```r
df %>%
  coalesce_plus_1(data = ., vars = all_of(starts_with("col")))

##   col_a col_b col_c coalesced_col
## 1  <NA>  <NA>  paul          paul
## 2  <NA> danny  <NA>         danny
## 3   bob  <NA>  <NA>           bob
## 4  <NA>  <NA>  paul          paul
## 5   bob  <NA>  <NA>           bob
```

---

***`coalesce_plus_2()`***

```r
df %>%
  coalesce_plus_2(data = ., vars = c(col_a, col_b, col_c))
```

> Error in lapply(.x, .f, ...) : object 'col_a' not found

And also

```r
df %>%
  coalesce_plus_2(data = ., vars = all_of(starts_with("col")))
```

> Error: `starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
> i See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

---

***`coalesce_plus_3()`***

```r
df %>%
  coalesce_plus_3(data = ., vars = c(col_a, col_b, col_c))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `coalesced_col`. x Input
> `coalesced_col` can't be recycled to size 5. i Input `coalesced_col`
> is `coalesce(c(col_a, col_b, col_c))`. i Input `coalesced_col` must be
> size 5 or 1, not 15.

And also

```r
df %>%
  coalesce_plus_3(data = ., vars = all_of(starts_with("col")))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `coalesced_col`.
> x `starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
> i See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html.
> i Input `coalesced_col` is `coalesce(all_of(starts_with("col")))`.

### Bottom line

How can I write a custom function for `coalesce()` that will take in a data object and specific column names to coalesce, allowing both specific naming e.g., `c(col_a, col_b, col_c)` and helper functions e.g., `starts_with("col")` in the function's `vars` argument?

Comment: Have you seen the `tidyselect` vignette on [Implementing tidyselect interfaces](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyselect/vignettes/tidyselect.html)?

Comment: very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a simple implementation that will only return the select columns, but could fairly easily extended to keep all columns (I'd `bind_cols` them back on at the end...).

It's simple because we rely on `select` to do the work for us, as suggested at the start of the [Implementing tidyselect vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyselect/vignettes/tidyselect.html)

```
# edited to keep all columns
coalesce_df = function(data, ...) {
  data %>%
    select(...) %>%
    transmute(result = invoke(coalesce, .)) %>%
    bind_cols(data, .)
}



df %>%
   coalesce_df(everything())
#   col_a col_b col_c result
# 1   bob  <NA>  paul    bob
# 2  <NA> danny  <NA>  danny
# 3   bob  <NA>  <NA>    bob
# 4  <NA>  <NA>  paul   paul
# 5   bob  <NA>  <NA>    bob

df %>% coalesce_df(col_a, col_b)
#   col_a col_b col_c result
# 1   bob  <NA>  paul    bob
# 2  <NA> danny  <NA>  danny
# 3   bob  <NA>  <NA>    bob
# 4  <NA>  <NA>  paul   <NA>
# 5   bob  <NA>  <NA>    bob
```

Comment: I took your hint about `bind_cols` and did the following in the function: `cols <- data %>% select(...) %>% names`, then the pipe with `mutate(result = invoke(coalesce, .))` as you suggested, and at the end of the pipe `bind_cols(., select(data, -all_of(cols)))`.

Comment: I just edited to use `transmute` instead of `mutate` which makes the keeping all columns a little cleaner - keeps them in their same order and adds the `result` column at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your first function works, just write `vars` as a character. Look:

```
df %>% coalesce_plus_1(data = ., vars = c("col_a","col_b","col_c"))
```

Here is another good option:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(col_a = c("bob", NA, "bob", NA, "bob"), 
                 col_b = c(NA, "danny", NA, NA, NA), 
                 col_c = c("paul", NA, NA, "paul", NA))

coalesce_plus <- function(data,vars){
      x <- as.list(select(data,vars))
      data.frame(data, coalesced_col=coalesce(!!!x))
}

df %>% coalesce_plus(data = ., vars = c("col_a","col_b","col_c"))
```